# Neo plugin - Displaying an image from a Matrix field

Tags: assets, matrix, plugin-neo

I am using the [Neo](https://github.com/benjamminf/craft-neo/wiki) plugin in my project. I have made a Neofield `article content` with several block types in it. Amongst the block types that I have in it, is a `gallery` as well. Gallery block type has a`matrix` field `imageWithCaption`, and the field `imageWithCaption` has fields `file` which is the assets field, and fields `imageTitle` and `caption` which are plain text fields. I am able to display `imageTitle` and `caption` in my template but not a file, or the image itself. This is my template:

```
     {% for image in block.imageWithCaption %}
        <div class="large-4 columns">
          <div class="media-object stack-for-small">
            <div class="media-object-section">
              <div>
                <img src="{{ image.file }}" alt="">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="media-object-section">
              <h6>{{ image.title }}</h6>
              <p>{{ image.caption }}</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      {% endfor %}
```

I get an error:

> Object of class Craft\ElementCriteriaModel could not be converted to
> string

What I am doing wrong and how can I display the image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's tough to see the full context, just based on what you have here. From what I can tell, it seems like you might need to change `<img src="{{ image.file }}" alt="">` to `<img src="{{ image.file.first().url }}" alt="">`.

Since the asset field can hold many assets, you have to declare `.first()` to grab the first one -- even if there's only one image. Then you have to grab the `url` property from the image, in order to get the correct `src` value.